# Design pattern for wargame interactions

Tags: class, design-patterns, interaction

I am working on a war game using java. This wargame has different fighting units. The units are for instance 'Human', 'Dwarf' and 'Elf' which all have their own properties. To accomodate these properties I currently have a class for 'Human', 'Dwarf' and 'Elf' which alle extend the abstract 'Unit' class.

Now I want to program a damage chart. For instance when human attacks a dwarf it's 56 damage. When dwarf attacks elf it's 27 damage. etc. Each interaction between units is unique and gives a number.

I'm am searching for a design pattern which makes it easy to add a new unit and update the damage chart so it interacts with each other unit. It should also make it easy to remove a unit

I thought about giving each unit a unique ID and putting a method such as this one in each unit.

```
public int getDamage(Unit defender) {
    switch(defender.getID() {
        case 0: return 27;
        case 1: return 50;
        ....
    }
}
```

But it seems very clunky to add or remove a unit this way because you have to alter the switch statement in each class that implements 'Unit'. It's also not very readable. I also thought about putting the switch statement in a separate 'Damage Chart' class. But this would require a switch statement for the attacker as well and creates nested switch statements (which is ugly).

Is there a clean way to solve this? Maybe a design pattern already exists for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is called "[double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)" and there are different solutions for it. For example if you have a given number of species and you not only care about attacks between them, but there are a growing number of different decisions (drawing, diplomacy, luck, etc.) that are all dependent on the actual species, you can use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: I would also suggest the visitor pattern. Combined with generics, it should do the job pretty well.

Comment: This would imply an AttackVisitor which visits the attacker and the defender in different modes.  You would write at least one method per attacker-defender combination.  There are (number of units, squared) such combinations.  This doesn't sound very manageable to me.

Comment: I would have to enter n^2 numbers eventually. Creating n^2 methods isn't that much different. It also keeps me from using id-numbers (which i hated) and it keeps the code readable. 
I does however seem a bit strange that my units are now both visitors and beiing visited. But I guess this is best solution! Thnx!

Comment: If you find a good way to calculate the table cells as h(f(attacker),g(defender)), you can have only 2n+1 methods. That is the maths part of your problem. Getting rid of the ids is the computer science part. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have the damage depend on attacker and defender on a case-by-case basis, you have to manage these numbers.  It is really a 2-dimensional matrix.  Whenever you add another unit, you need to add two times the current number of units (one row and one column) values to that matrix.  I would use a 2-dimensional array for this.

If you have a lot of units, this becomes quickly quite tedious.  I would propose to use something like attack and defense ratings (e. g. dwarven axeman 30/20), tagging units with "what they are" (e. g. elves, dwarves) and a few specials (e. g. +4/+1 against elves; or -5/0 against axemen).  That way, you can add a new unit, apply a few tags and specials to it, and be done, since the rest is a simple calculation.

In other words: I think you have a data problem, not a language problem.